# cloning an opencv Mat performance

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, buffer, mat

I have a pointer to a buffer image. I'm trying to create a cv::Mat and assign it my buffer image. The only way i found is by doing

```
uchar* buffer; //have some data in it
cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC1, buffer); //which won't copy the data, will use the pointer as reference
```

The problem is I don't have ownership of that buffer. So I can either :

1. create a mat and assign it that buffer, than do a copyTo itself. (which is the same thing than I clone())
2. do a malloc and memcpy of that buffer (so i have a pointer that i own) and create a mat from it. (which is much faster).

Is the method #2 wrong? Why is it so much faster?

Bonus questions: What is hapenning to my buffer memory when I do operation on my mat? Is it getting resized? Is it getting updated (if i do a cv::flip, will it update the original buffer) ? And why is the clone() so expensive?

Sorry for the multiple questions, but I think they are all related and will help me to understand a little bit better the cv::Mat structure.

Comment: Could you quantify "so much faster"?  How big is the data? Also, have you compiled in debug mode (assertion checks can be expensive)?. Could you post the code for your two different approaches?

Comment: as a side note, if you copy to itself, (ie sampleMat.copyTo(sampleMat)), sampleMat.data is unchanged